# Fetch number of affected rows and last inserted ID using PDO statement

Tags: php, pdo

How can I display the numbers of affected rows in this:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare ("UPDATE countries SET country=:country");
$sql->bindValue(":country", "blablaa");
$sql->execute();
```

And how can I show the last inserted ID with this:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (:country)");
$sql->bindValue(":country", "test");
$sql->execute();
echo $sql->lastInsertId(); // id of last inserted
```

I tried, but am receiving an error call to undefined method `PDO::lastInsertId()`

Answer (score 12):

I think this can help you:

> PDOStatement::rowCount()

returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 7):

```
$sql->lastInsertId();
```

Needs to be replaced with

```
$dbh->lastInsertId();
```

Where $dbh is your PDO object.

See [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#12) for more information.

[`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) returns the number of affected rows, [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) only returns a true or false value.

Comment: I cant get it to work with $dbh->lastInsertId();. In the link you provided It says $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO..." but thats double work I mean I have the $sql with prepare above, why would i write all that again in order to echo out last inserted..? i am missing something, could you write example of my code on how you would echo lastinsertid() ?

Comment: In your case, you are using `$conn` as your PDO object, so try `$conn->lastInsertId();`